# Unable to see created database and table in hive in specified location

Tags: database, hive, hdfs

1. I created database using SQL in hive.
   And I looked for the database using HDFS.
   But I couldn't find database in HDFS.

   In hive:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE practice
   LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse'/
   ```

   Checking:

   ```
   hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
   ```

   There is nothing in warehouse.
2. In addition, I created a table in a specific database in hive.
   But, using Hue, I could see the table in the default location.
   I wanna insert the table into a specific database location.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE prac (
       id INT,
       title STRING,
       salary INT,
       posted TIMESTAMP
   )
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/practice.db/prac';
   ```

   I couldn't find the table `prac` in the database `practice` in Hue and HDFS.

How can I see the database in HDFS?
And I also wanna know how to see the table in the specific database location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by specifying **`db name`** while creating hive table `prac` by default hive creates tables in `default` database.

**`Example:`**

```
hive> CREATE DATABASE practice LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/practice.db';

hive> CREATE TABLE `practice.prac` ( id INT, title STRING, salary INT, posted TIMESTAMP ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/practice.db/prac';
```

Comment: Your answer helped me really a lot. I solved this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using below command:

CREATE DATABASE practice
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/practice.db';

hive by default uses '/user/hive/warehouse/' directory to create databases under this location. So while creating database, If you don't provide the location it will pick the database location like this '/user/hive/warehouse/practice.db'.

You can choose any location over hdfs until you have read and write permission over that location.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. But I can't find a database in practice.db.